# Camera rotation in cesium.js

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to make  my Cesium camera should follow the Line which I've created.Please check the below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwWEE.jpg)

I want my cesium Camera should focus on red car which is shown in the image.
Please check the following link for further information
http://cesiumjs.org/demos/Taipei3DCityNavigation.html

Answer (score 2):

Typically these kinds of apps use a Cesium Entity for the car, and the line is the path that the car takes over time.  In this case, tracking with the camera is just a matter of setting `viewer.trackedEntity` to the appropriate entity.

The code snippet below is kind of large just to get a vehicle crossing a bridge, but the important line is at the bottom of the JS, where it sets `trackedEntity`.

*EDIT:* Added a new `"viewFrom"` property in the CZML below, to control the default camera angle used to track the Entity anytime it is selected for tracking.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false
});


var builtInCzml = [{
    "id" : "document",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "clock" : {
      "interval" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z/2012-08-04T16:02:00Z",
      "currentTime" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z",
      "multiplier" : 1,
      "range" : "LOOP_STOP",
      "step" : "SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER"
    }
}, {
    "id" : "Vehicle",
    "availability" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z/2012-08-04T16:02:00Z",
    "viewFrom" : {
        "cartesian" : [ -200, 50, 50 ]
    },
    "billboard" : {
        "eyeOffset" : {
            "cartesian" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        },
        "horizontalOrigin" : "CENTER",
        "image" : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAEISURBVEhLvVXBDYQwDOuojHKj8LhBbpTbpBCEkZsmIVTXq1RVQGrHiWlLmTTqPiZBlyLgy/KSZQ5JSHDQ/mCYCsC8106kDU0AdwRnvYZArWRcAl0dcYJq1hWCb3hBrumbDAVMwAC82WoRvgMnVMDBnB0nYZFTbE6BBvdUGqVqCbjBIk3PyFFR/NU7EKzru+qZsau3ryPwwCRLKYOzutZuCL6fUmWeJGzNzL/RxAMrUmASSCkkAayk2IxPlwhAAYGpsiHQjbLccfdOY5gKkCXAMi7SscAwbQpAnKyctWyUZ6z8ja3OGMepwD8asz+9FnSvbhU8uVOHFIwQsI3/p0CfhuqCSQuxLqsN6mu8SS+N42MAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
        "pixelOffset" : {
            "cartesian2" : [0.0, 0.0]
        },
        "scale" : 0.8,
        "show" : true,
        "verticalOrigin" : "BOTTOM"
    },
    "label" : {
        "fillColor" : {
            "rgba" : [255, 255, 0, 255]
        },
        "font" : "bold 10pt Segoe UI Semibold, sans-serif",
        "horizontalOrigin" : "LEFT",
        "outlineColor" : {
            "rgba" : [0, 0, 0, 255]
        },
        "pixelOffset" : {
            "cartesian2" : [10.0, 0.0]
        },
        "scale" : 1.0,
        "show" : true,
        "style" : "FILL",
        "text" : "Vehicle",
        "verticalOrigin" : "CENTER"
    },
    "path" : {
        "material" : {
            "solidColor" : {
                "color" : {
                    "rgba" : [255, 255, 0, 255]
                }
            }
        },
        "width" : 5.0,
        "show" : true
    },
    "position" : {
        "interpolationAlgorithm" : "LAGRANGE",
        "interpolationDegree" : 1,
        "epoch" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z",
        "cartesian" : [0.0, 1254962.0093268978, -4732330.528380746, 4074172.505865612,
                       120.0, 1256995.7322857284, -4732095.2154790815, 4073821.2249589274]
    }
}];

var dataSource = new Cesium.CzmlDataSource();
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
dataSource.load(builtInCzml).then(function() {
  
    // Track with camera
    viewer.trackedEntity = dataSource.entities.getById('Vehicle');
    
});
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @emackey. It is working fine. But the camera angle is from side view, I want to follow the vehicle from the backside of the vehicle

Comment: I added a CZML property `viewFrom` to set the default camera angle for tracking.  It's a Cartesian3, +Z is local up.

Comment: Thank you emackey ,its working fine, the above code is only for 2 Cartesian points. if i want to do the same action for multiple points,what i can do? I've tried of givinng all the points as follows :

Comment: "cartesian":0.0,1230609.80908732,5961807.45414746,1897108.00810864,60.00,1230602.50370271,5961808.68839746,1897108.86244386,60.00,1230602.50370271,5961808.68839746,1897108.86244386,60.00,1230602.17608108,5961807.88018509,1897111.59640414,60.00,1230601.02718762,5961806.91857004,1897115.33837883,60.00,1230599.6604567,5961806.52044253,1897117.46176467,60.00,1230599.66045671,5961806.52044253,1897117.46176466,60.00,1230599.57246954,5961806.49481191,1897117.59846361,60.00,1230598.31793552,5961806.12936627,1897119.54753754,60.00,1230594.46381745,5961805.92761192,1897122.66061319                 ]

Comment: Currently Cesium doesn't have built-in support for automatically moving the camera like that, you would have to add it to the app.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. 
SCENARIO: person is walking in a non-linear path.
PROBLEM: want to change the direction of camera of a tracked entity, 
i.e camera should turn when the person takes a turn in the path.

Comment: Hi  emackey, time being I'm rotating the camera by using set timeouts,but there is a lot of jerks while navigating. Is there any alternative way to achieve smooth navigation for a non-linear path with camera rotation.

Comment: Yes, you can add an event callback such as `viewer.clock.onTick.subscribe(callback)` and set the camera position in the callback.

Comment: as cesium doesnot support camera rotation along with the tracked entity. to achieve this i tried one way,

Comment: Myclass.prototype.startNav = function(cameraHeight,pitchAngle,moveCamera)
{ this.time = 0.0;var navCalback = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < this.pathArray.length; i++) {var currPath = this.pathArray[i];for (var j = 0 ; j < currPath.ReturnList.length-1 ; j++) {
var x1 = currPath.ReturnList[j].X
var y1 = currPath.ReturnList[j].Y
var x2 = currPath.ReturnList[j + 1].X
var y2 = currPath.ReturnList[j + 1].Y
this.navigationHelper(x1, y1, x2, y2,cameraHeight,pitchAngle,moveCamera);}
}}.bind(this); this.flyTo(nav.startPoint.X, nav.startPoint.Y,cameraHeight,180,pitchAngle,moveCamera, navCalback);}

Comment: Myclass.prototype.navigationHelper = function(x1,y1,x2,y2,cameraHeight,pitchAngle,moveCamera)
{ 
 setTimeout(
  function () {
   var angle = this.getAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
      this.setView(x1,y1,cameraHeight,90-angle,pitchAngle,moveCamera);                
  }.bind(this),
 this.time * 1000); // use time
 // navigate
 var builtInCzml = this.getCZMLFor2Points(x1, y1, x2, y2);
 var dataSource = new Cesium.CzmlDataSource();
 this.viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
 dataSource.load(builtInCzml);
}

Comment: I've divided my non-linear path as multiple lines and by using setTimeouts im changing the camera roatiion for each turn. but im facing so many problems with setTimeouts, even though i stopped navigation, camera is moving to  particular loaction, this is happening untill last Settimeout is finished.Can you tell me where i should apply viewer.clock.onTick.subscribe(callback). please check the above functions

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what the demo `Multi-part CZML` is doing:

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Multi-part%20CZML.html&label=All

This is the code:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    shouldAnimate : true
});

var statusDisplay = document.createElement('div');
var fuelDisplay = document.createElement('div');
var czmlPath = '../../../../Apps/SampleData/';
var vehicleEntity;

// Add a blank CzmlDataSource to hold our multi-part entity/entities.
var dataSource = new Cesium.CzmlDataSource();
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);

// This demo shows how a single path can be broken up into several CZML streams.
var partsToLoad = [{
    url: 'MultipartVehicle_part1.czml',
    range: [0, 1500],
    requested: false,
    loaded: false
}, {
    url: 'MultipartVehicle_part2.czml',
    range: [1500, 3000],
    requested: false,
    loaded: false
}, {
    url: 'MultipartVehicle_part3.czml',
    range: [3000, 4500],
    requested: false,
    loaded: false
}];

function updateStatusDisplay() {
    var msg = '';
    partsToLoad.forEach(function(part) {
        msg += part.url + ' - ';
        if (part.loaded) {
            msg += 'Loaded.<br/>';
        } else if (part.requested) {
            msg += 'Loading now...<br/>';
        } else {
            msg += 'Not needed yet.<br/>';
        }
    });
    statusDisplay.innerHTML = msg;
}

// Helper function to mark a part as requested, and process it into the dataSource.
function processPart(part) {
    part.requested = true;
    updateStatusDisplay();
    dataSource.process(czmlPath + part.url).then(function() {
        part.loaded = true;
        updateStatusDisplay();

        // Follow the vehicle with the camera.
        if (!viewer.trackedEntity) {
            viewer.trackedEntity = vehicleEntity = dataSource.entities.getById('Vehicle');
        }
    });
}

// Load the first part up front.
processPart(partsToLoad[0]);

// Load a new section before the clock naturally gets there.
// Note this can't predict when a user may fast-forward to it.
var preloadTimeInSeconds = 100;

viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function(clock) {
    // This example uses time offsets from the start to identify which parts need loading.
    var timeOffset = Cesium.JulianDate.secondsDifference(clock.currentTime, clock.startTime);

    // Filter the list of parts to just the ones that need loading right now.
    // Then, process each part that needs loading.
    partsToLoad.filter(function(part) {
        return (!part.requested) &&
            (timeOffset >= part.range[0] - preloadTimeInSeconds) &&
            (timeOffset <= part.range[1]);
    }).forEach(function(part) {
        processPart(part);
    });

    if (vehicleEntity) {
        var fuel = vehicleEntity.properties.fuel_remaining.getValue(clock.currentTime);
        if (Cesium.defined(fuel)) {
            fuelDisplay.textContent = 'Fuel: ' + fuel.toFixed(2) + ' gal';
        }
    }
});

// Add a reset button, for convenience.
Sandcastle.addToolbarButton('Reset demo', function() {
    // Put things back to the starting position.
    viewer.clock.currentTime = viewer.clock.startTime;
    viewer.clock.shouldAnimate = true;

    partsToLoad.forEach(function(part) {
        part.requested = false;
        part.loaded = false;
    });

    dataSource.entities.removeAll();
    processPart(partsToLoad[0]);
});

// Show the status display below the reset button.
statusDisplay.style.background = 'rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.7)';
statusDisplay.style.padding = '5px 10px';
document.getElementById('toolbar').appendChild(statusDisplay);

// Show a multi-part custom property being read from CZML.
fuelDisplay.style.background = 'rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.7)';
fuelDisplay.style.padding = '5px 10px';
fuelDisplay.style.marginTop = '5px';
document.getElementById('toolbar').appendChild(fuelDisplay);
```